# Recommendation algo for completing a set

Tags: recommender-system

In Gmail, when I start typing out the "to" field, it suggests people to add to the email, based on whom I usually email together. **Does anyone know where I can find a simple algorithm of this type, or what this would be called?**

In particular, let's say I have friends named: A, B, C, D, E, F, G, .... I sometimes send group emails to ABCD, and sometimes to ABEF. If I start writing to AB, it should recommend either C or E, and if I choose C, it should then suggest D (basically refining the suggestion after each item is added).

The algorithm needs to be able to work with inputs it hasn't seen before. For example, if I start addressing to ABCZ, it should still recommend D, because that is associated with 3 of the 4 inputs.

**EDIT:** currently I have implemented it based on frequency (the element that has been associated with the most inputs). I would prefer to use conditional probability, like pre-calculating every combination such as `P(C|AB)` and `P(D|ABC)` etc but in my case this would be too many combinations to store since there are many inputs and they change all the time.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I found Google's paper [here](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/36371.pdf).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).